# Add Explores to Model - nothing shows up

Tags: looker

I have two models, A and B, Both models contain multiple Explores and everything works without issue.

User John asked me to add two Explores from model A to model B. I edited Model B's lookML in development mode, validated, committed....and nothing.

The Explores I added are not showing. I have Admin permissions (it's a sandbox), nothing is set to "hidden:yes".

What am I missing here?